# Health Checks failing for an ingress created on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, consul, gke-networking

I'm creating a load balancer for consul ui on GKE using ingress with the following configs

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: public-apis
spec:
  rules:
    - host: consul.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ui/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: hashicorp-consul-ui
              servicePort: http
```

The service `hashicorp-consul-ui` is a service of type clusterIP.

Also, I'm creating the following backendConfig

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: consul-ui-backendconfig
spec:
  healthCheck:
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /v1/health/state/failed
    port: 80
```

I'm adding the following annotation to the clusterIP service `hashicorp-consul-ui`

`'cloud.google.com/backend-config': '{"ports": {"80":"consul-ui-backendconfig"}}'`

This backendConfig creates health check for the backend service created by ingress, this endpoint returns 200. But the health check fails and the ingress is in Unhealthy state

I've enabled log on healthCheck and I'm getting the following log on NEG

```
healthCheckProbeResult: {
   detailedHealthState: "TIMEOUT"    
   healthCheckProtocol: "HTTP"    
   healthState: "UNHEALTHY"    
   ipAddress: "10.24.1.30"    
   previousDetailedHealthState: "UNKNOWN"    
   previousHealthState: "UNHEALTHY"    
   probeCompletionTimestamp: "2021-02-14T03:31:43.337063261Z"    
   probeRequest: "/v1/health/state/failed"    
   probeResultText: "HTTP response: , Error: Connection refused"    
   probeSourceIp: "35.191.9.211"    
   responseLatency: "0.001265s"    
   targetIp: "10.24.1.30"    
   targetPort: 80    
}
```

Also, not sure why I got this log only once, shouldn't I be getting these logs at regular interval?

Also, can anyone guide me about how can I fix this healthCheck issue?

Comment: Could you provide the output of the command `kubectl describe pod <podname>`. Also make sure that you have the [required firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#firewall_rules) for health checks to work.

Comment: @Dylan yes, the firewall rules are already present. The gke ingress controller does all that I guess while create a load balancer. Sorry, I've deleted all the resources now but the pod was health and was serving request via port-forwarding.

Answer (score -1):

The Consul API/UI listens on port 8500 by default, or 8501 when TLS is enabled in the cluster.

Change your ingress `servicePort` to use port 8500. That should resolve the connectivity issue.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: public-apis
spec:
  rules:
    - host: consul.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ui/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: hashicorp-consul-ui
              servicePort: 8500
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention this but the service maps the port 8500 to 80